# Is Chrome Native Messaging API part of Chrome Apps or Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-native-messaging

I'm wondering if the Native Messaging API is a part of Chrome Apps?

I have found documentation for Chrome Native Messaging in both places

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging
and
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging.

Chrome Apps will reach its end of life support in 2022.

I have read through migration information for Chrome Apps but couldn't find anything about Native Messaging API.
(such as chrome.runtime.connectNative)

Comment: Both apps an extensions can use it. There is no relation.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of [extension API](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/messaging/)

After excluding the Apps API, extensions will still be able to use the Native Messaging.